# Excel Conditional Formatting References Phrase

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, gantt-chart

I'm trying to recreate a Gantt chart found on the MS website (link below) but the conditional formatting is referencing what appears to be personalized cell references, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  I just need to know what this is referencing so I can reverse engineer the process.

(https://templates.office.com/en-us/Gantt-project-planner-TM02887601?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

I've already reviewed any possible macros and also looked for cell references, but the ones listed are not related to the conditional formatting.  I've also looked at the VBA data, which I'm not really knowledgeable about.  I know to look there and to tweak macros, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are referencing Named Ranges. Named Ranges are really useful with conditional formatting. You can find the named ranged in the Formula's tab of the ribbon

**Named Ranges:** 
[image: Named Ranges]

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks for the info.